# Find last duplicate character from string

Tags: python, string

I have a string `abbccdeefght`,I want to find the last duplicate character from the string.
For above string the result should be character 'e'.
I tried using `Counter` from `collections` module in python.

```
from collections import Counter
c=Counter('abbccdeefght')
c

>>> Counter({'c': 2, 'b': 2, 'e': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, 'f': 1, 'h': 1, 't': 1})
```

but not sure how to proceed

Comment: In your example string, all of the duplicate characters are right next to each other.  If you start with the string "abba", do you want "a" or "b" to be returned?

Comment: if i have a string like "abba" then 'a' should be returned

Answer (score 1):

This way you will get *index* of last duplicate character

```
def last_duplicate(line):
    c=Counter(line)
    #>>> Counter({'c': 2, 'b': 2, 'e': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, 'f': 1, 'h': 1, 't': 1})

    for i, x in reversed(line):
        if c[x] > 1:
            return len(line) - i - 1
```

Surely you can find character itself easy enough

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is equivalent to finding the first duplicated character, if you move from right to left. For each character you check if it is already contained in the part to the right.

Something like this:

```
my_string = "abbccdeefght"
for idx in range(len(my_string) - 2, -1, -1):
    char = my_string[idx]
    if char in my_string[idx + 1:]:
        print("Last duplicated character is: " + char)
        break
```

Explanation: Using `range` we iterate `idx` from number that is 2 less than the lenght of the string, all the way to 0. Every time we take a character from position `idx` and see if it is already contained in the part of `my_string` that is to the right of character at position `idx`. If it is, we do `print()` and end our loop.

Edit:
Upon your further explanation, here is fixed code (it wasn't clear from your question). Now we also iterate characters from right to left, but check if the character is contained in the part to the *left*.

```
my_string = "abba"
for idx in range(len(my_string) - 1, 0, -1):
    char = my_string[idx]
    if char in my_string[:idx]:
        print("Last duplicated character is: " + char)
        break
```

Comment: This would fail in case if we have a string like 'abba' ,the expected result is 'a' here but it would return me 'b'

Answer (score 0):

```
input_string='abbccdeefght'

last_duplicate_string=[single_letter for single_letter in input_string if input_string.count(single_letter) > 1]

if last_duplicate_string:
    print "Last duplicate character from the string %s",last_duplicate_string[-1]
else:
    print "No duplicate character"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple algorithm

```
mystr = 'abbccdeefght'
size = len(mystr)-1
found = 0
i=0
while (1):
    if (mystr[size]==mystr[i]):
        print ("found ",mystr[size]," on index ",i+1," and index ",size+1)
        break
    i+=1
    if (i==size):
        i=0
        size-=1
    if (size==1):
        print ("not found")
        break
```

The loops will break upon 2 condition. Found and no more data to be checked. 
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Tested for "", "abba", "zzasd", "zxcv", "abbccdeefght"

```
# enumerates reversed list
def reverse_enumerate(seq):
    p = -1
    for elem in seq[::-1]:
        yield p, elem
        p -= 1

str = "abbccdeefght"

for i, c in reverse_enumerate(str):
    # check element in left side
    if c in str[i-1::-1]:
        print(c, i)
        # print element, position
        break
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow, please elaborate and describe your answer, it's easier to understand

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'abbccdeefght'
a=a[::-1] #reverse the string and helps to get the last repeating characters
for char in a:
    counter = a.count(char) #checking count of the character in string
    if counter > 1: #if count is greater than 1 then it is duplicate
        print(char+' is the last repeting character in string') #printing the result
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this I quite pretty solution:

```
from collections import Counter
c=dict(Counter('abbccdeefght'))# get counts as dictionary
last_duplicate = list(filter(lambda k: c[k] == 2, c.keys()))[-1]#get only duplicates and take the last one
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution this works for fine for the given string,but would fail if we have duplicate characters not occuring right next to each other like "abba",then the following code needs to be modified like this:                 ``from collections import Counter
c=dict(Counter('abbccdeefght'))# get counts as dictionary
last_duplicate = list(filter(lambda k: c[k] >= 1, c.keys()))[-1]``#get only duplicates and take the last one